# How to write a Splunk query to get the result for every hour in a day?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am trying to fetch the results based on Splunk search for every hour in a day. I want to add the timestamp in the results. I'm expecting 24 rows in the result each row is considered as one hour data with timestamp mentioned in each row per day.

**My basic query:**

```
index = 'xyz' sourcetype='abc' status='completed'
```

How can I modifying the query in the below format?

```
time status
1am  completed
2am  completed
..    ...
11pm completed
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [`timechart`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/timechart) will suffice?

```
index='xyz' sourcetype='abc' status='completed'
| timechart span=1h count by status
```

Comment: Tried with this query but it is showing no results found . Without timechart line it is displaying proper data. Do not know why this is happening wierdly .

Comment: My query looks like this : index='xyz' sourcetype='abc' status='completed' | stats count(eval(_raw like "similar")) as similar_events | timechart span=1h count by status

Comment: Warren .. Can you please help me with the query ?

Comment: Can we use stats and timechart command at the same time ?

Comment: Yes, `stats` and `timechart` can be used in the same query, but you have to be careful about it.  The `timechart` command requires the _time field, which `stats` will discard if the field is not explicitly mentioned.  In the example, `stats` adds no value because it produces a field (similar_events) that is not used.

Comment: @dev333 - did you try what I suggested before adding the additional `stats` line? As RichG points out, `stats` throws-out the `_time` field which `timechart` requires

Comment: It worked for me  in this way by removing stats and introduced timechart with 1hr span . index='xyz' sourcetype='abc' status='completed' | timechart span=1hr count(eval(_raw like "similar"))